# Unity error while loading configuration: The type ObjectContext has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate

Tags: c#, configuration, repository, unity-container

Hell o,

I have a problem to register a repository with unity container. I have a following configuration and classes:

/* Generic repository: */

```
public class Repository<E> : IRepository<E> where E : EntityObject
{
    private readonly ObjectContext _ctx;

    public ObjectContext Context
    {
        get { return _ctx; }
    }

    public Repository(ObjectContext context)
    {
       _ctx = context;            
    }
}
```

/* Concrete repository: */

```
public class SourceRepository : Repository<Source>
{
    public SourceRepository(EntityContext context) : base(context) { }    
}
```

/* EF generated context: */

```
public partial class EntityContext : ObjectContext
{
    public EntityContext() : base("name=EntityContext", "EntityContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    public EntityContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "EntityContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    public EntityContext(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "EntityContext")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
}
```

/* Registration of EntityContext type with constructor without parameters */

```
<register type="ObjectContext" mapTo="EntityContext" name="EntityContext">
    <constructor/>
</register>
```

/* Registration for generic repository (I'm not sure if this registration is needed) */

```
<register type="IRepository[]" mapTo="Repository[]" name="Repository">
    <lifetime type="transient" />
    <constructor>
        <param name="context">
            <dependency name="EntityContext"/>
        </param>
    </constructor>
</register>
```

/* Registration for concrete repository. I want to inject constructor dependency of EntityContext type */

```
<register type="IRepository[Source]" mapTo="SourceRepository" name="SourceRepository">
    <lifetime type="transient" />
    <constructor>
        <param name="context">
            <dependency name="EntityContext"/>
        </param>
    </constructor>
</register>
```

When I'm trying to load configuration I'm getting error:

**Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "BL.DataAccess.Repository.SourceRepository", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ObjectContext has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.**

I understand what this exception means, but I don't know where I have an error in my configuration.

Can you help please?

thanks.

Comment: Specifying EntityContext as the parameter type in the Constructor configuration might do the trick.

Comment: if you mean this: <constructor>
        <param name="context" type="EntityContext">
            <dependency name="EntityContext"/>
        </param>
    </constructor>
so it didn't help. The same error.

Comment: Looks SourceRepository has only one constractor. Can you try  Type t = typeof(SourceRepository); ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfos = t.GetConstructors(); to check how many contractors it has.

Comment: yes, it has the only one constructor

Comment: Does the `SourceRepository` constructor take an `EntityContext`, like your code here? Or does it actually take an `ObjectContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of the exception, `Resolve` is being called for an unnamed registration for `SourceRepository`.

Either ensure your configuration sets up all classes which depend on `SourceRepository` to use the correct named registration (through `<param><dependency name="SourceRepository" /></param>`).

Or remove the name in the source repository registration, so you'd end up with:

```
<register type="IRepository[Source]" mapTo="SourceRepository">
    <lifetime type="transient" />
    <constructor>
        <param name="context">
            <dependency name="EntityContext"/>
        </param>
    </constructor>
</register>
```